# Why does MySQL refuse pipe ('|') character in string on INSERT INTO

Tags: sql, mysql

If I try this statement:

```
INSERT INTO TerminalEventChild (id,stringValue) VALUES 
(64,'version123|');
```

MySQL fail with :

```
Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''version123' at line 1
SQLState:  42000
ErrorCode: 1064
```

If I remove the | character, everything works fine. Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried escape the | with a backslash?

Comment: Yep, and I got the same thing. I also tried to double the pipe but with same result.

Comment: This applies to **SQL Squirrel Client**. See the answer below: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7444934/1188357

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On my machine, this works fine:

```
CREATE TABLE TerminalEventChild (id INT, stringValue VARCHAR(200));

INSERT INTO TerminalEventChild (id,stringValue) VALUES
(64,'version123|');
```

Probably, your client treats the pipe character specially.

What client do you use?

Comment: Right, I just tried with the mysql command line and it worked fine. I am using SQuirreLSQL. I will check with them. Thanks you!

Comment: I can also confirm this works. I tried it using the mysql cli (5.1.42) on a Linux box.

Answer (score 18):

I found the solution on [Incorrect query parsing - ID: 3091322](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=3091322&group_id=28383&atid=393414).
Squirrel SQL is using the pipe symbol as a procedure/function separator, so you need to change the MySQL preferences to use something else (e.g. *|||*).

In the "File > Global Preferences > MySQL" tab, in the "Procedure/Function Separator" field, 
replace *|* with a different string, for example *|||*.

Comment: Worked in my case, Squirrel pipe handling was the culprit.

Comment: I'm using squirrel and this was my problem as well. Didn't know Squirrel used the pipe for other stuff.